# Removing data based on value from rows with spaces

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to this, so I am sorry for the simple question. I am currently trying to remove rows based on values from the data frame right now I can make it work, but only if I remove a column with no space in between. So my question is without renaming Host Name to a one word or adding an underscore how can I get this to work ? I currently have this

```
info.columns = ['Host Name', 'Space']
info

output: 
Host Name           Space
Desktop123           500
desktop213           500
desktop              Node


info=info[info.Host Name !='Node']
info.head()

File "<ipython-input-24-2800ffbe7476>", line 1
    info=info[info.'Host Name' !='Node']
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please take a moment to format your code as code using the `{}` buttons, and provide the full error traceback. A sample of your data would also be helpful (`info.head()`) perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`info=info[info.Host Name !='Node']`

TO:

```
info=info[info['Host Name'] !='Node']
```

Comment: I hope I understood your question correctly. Let me know if this works. Generally it's good coding practice to call pandas columns using df['column name'] not as df.columnname.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying to figure out  that little error for hours

Comment: You are welcome! Pandas syntax can be a little hard to understand because there is so many ways of doing the same thing :), but under certain conditions, only one way works.